# Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs

hello i working with angularjs so i have a array with `branch->client->invoice->details_invoice`, now invoice have a total for each invoice, i do a function for sum all invoice for each client.

```
var TotalInvoice=0;
$scope.getSubTotal=function(indexClient,indexBranch){

            var ret="0";
            if($scope.data!=null){
                var invoice=$scope.data[0].branch[indexBranch].client[indexClient].invoice;
                if(invoice!=null){

                    for(var $i=0;$i<invoice.length;$i++){
                        if(invoice[$i].state=="3"){
                            ret=boletas[$i].amount;                             
                            TotalInvoice+=parseFloat(boletas[$i].amount);

                            }                       
                        }

                    }
            }

             return (parseInt(ret)).toFixed(2);
             };
```

and for total

```
   $scope.getTotalInvoice=function(){
    return (parseInt(TotalInvoice)).toFixed(2);
    };
```

but i have this error

```
    Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:

 [[.....
```

if i delete the line `TotalInvoice+=parseFloat(boletas[$i].amount);` the error disappears, please help me

**update add html**

```
<div ng-repeat="branch in company.branch| filter: { id_branch:id_b}"  >
   <tr  ng-repeat="client in branch.client.slice(page.ini,page.fin) >
 <td>{{getSubTotal(company.branch.indexOf(branch ),branch.client.indexOf(client))}}</td>
  </tr>
<tr> {{getTotalInvoice()}}</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Where in your HTML are you using `getSubTotal` or `getTotalInvoice` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand how your application is suppose to work. Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XUdht9AKsOuQYwA8sRHz?p=preview) example even close to accomplishing what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Every time your `getSubTotal()` function is called, it increments the value of TotalInvoice. Since TotalInvoice is also displayed in the UI, it's watched, and its change causes `getSubTotal()` to be called again, which increments TotalInvoice, etc. etc.

`TotalInvoice` should probably set to 0 every time `getSubTotal()` is called. Or better, `getSubTotal()` shouldn't set TotalInvoice at all. That's not its job.

Comment: if do it always totalinvoice return only subtotal, so the result is the last client sub total

Comment: You should have a getTotalInvoice function in your controller that computes the total invoice. The total invoice shouldn't be the result of N invocations of getSubTotal() from the view. Those two functions should be independent, and have no side effect.

Comment: i think in that too, but i have many tables :income, expenses, profit and balance, is the only way to do that? I always try to create the least amount of functions and variables

Comment: You can also compute the total once and for all, when the data is loaded, and store it in a variable.